# call aws sdk file it shows blank screen using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Here my code this code work perfect in  localhost but not work in server

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = $new_api_fields['bucket'];
$keyname = $new_api_fields['keyname'];
$secret = $new_api_fields['secret'];
// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory([
    'key' =>$keyname,
    'secret' =>$secret,
]);
$object = $s3->getIterator("ListObjects",[
    'Bucket' =>$bucket,
    'Prefix' =>'/ReportJan2016/'   
]);
```

please help me...

Comment: your code is looking fine. Have you iterated `$object` in `foreach`? Reference http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#listing-objects-in-your-buckets

Comment: yes i iterated in foreach  foreach ($object as $key => $value)
    {    
        //Iteration for getting a latest json.
        $temp_last_modified = explode('T',$value['LastModified']);    
        $ext = pathinfo($value['Key'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $temp_last_date = $temp_last_modified[0]; 
        if(($last_date < $temp_last_date) && ($ext == 'json'))
        {
            $last_date = $temp_last_date;
            $key_val = $value['Key'];
            $ext = pathinfo($key_val, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }
    }

Comment: after $object i print some text that text does not print but before $s3 text text will printing... actually this my path \vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\S3\S3Client above use statement correct or not (Aws\S3\S3Client;)

Comment: in my local php version 5.5.6 in server 5.3.3 ..is it is version problem .??? .USE keyword work on version 5.3.3????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
    )
));
```

Comment: not working ... i think use Aws\S3\S3Client; path is wrong.S3Client file present in html\portal\cloud_ip_automation\AWS\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\S3

Comment: This is not path this is `namespace`.

Comment: ya its namespace

Comment: same code working in localhost but not work in server

Comment: Have you checked for difference in version of AWS SDK?